# Android:send data from Service to activity with broadcastReceiver Error

Tags: android, service, android-activity, broadcastreceiver

I'm trying to send data from my service to the activity, but I'm getting an error:

> SEND_DATA_INTENT cannot be resolved to a variable

This is the code I'm using. I hope someone will guide me to resolve this problem.

This onTaskCompleted method, from which I'll send data to activity

```
public class DownloadService extends Service  implements OnTaskCompleted {
public void onTaskCompleted(String result){
            
            Log.i("receiving*******-----------",results+"");
            Intent intent = new Intent();//SEND_DATA_INTENTs
            intent.putExtra("type", "message");
            sendBroadcast(intent);
            
        }
}
```

This the main class, in which I created a brodcastReceiver class to receive data from Service:

```
 public class MainActivity extends Activity {
 private class DataReciver extends BroadcastReceiver
            {
                @Override
                public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
                {
                    if (intent.getAction().equals(DownloadService.MSG_SET_INT_VALUE)) //
                    {
                        Bundle bdl = intent.getExtras();
                        String type = bdl.getString("type");
                        Log.i("DataReciver","/////"+type);
                        
                        
                    }
                }
            }
}
```

Comment: Use something like new Intent("CUSTOM_ACTION") and register your broadcast receiver for "CUSTOM_ACTION".

Comment: even if i use CUSTOM_ACTION ,i have the same error @shkschneider

Comment: Where do you use and/or define SEND_DATA_INTENT? Is this in your code, 'cause I don't see it in your excerpts except in comment.

Comment: i didn't dified it ,i thought that this like a default variable. And how should i define it : type ,default value ?

Comment: java101, constant definitions. unrelated to android, activity, broadcastreceiver, service. Only plain Java.

Comment: It is not. I'm not sure what is it that you're trying to do here, but a variable needs to be defined. Go back to your example (if any) or do like I proposed on my first comment.

Comment: So how shloud i define it , to go with context ?

Answer (score 0):

After a little search i found a solution : Binding to a Service.
And this is a working example , i hope it will help someone :

In the DownloadService class :service

```
     public class DownloadService extends Service  implements OnTaskCompleted {
    private final IBinder mBinder = new LocalBinder();
         // Random number generator
        private final Random mGenerator = new Random();
     /**
             * Class used for the client Binder.  Because we know this service always
             * runs in the same process as its clients, we don't need to deal with IPC.
             */
            public class LocalBinder extends Binder {
                DownloadService getService() {
                    // Return this instance of LocalService so clients can call public methods
                    return DownloadService.this;
                }
            }
            @Override
            public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {

                return mBinder;
            }
     /** method for clients */
            public int getRandomNumber() {
              return mGenerator.nextInt(100);
            }
}
```

This the main Activty :that will receive the number when clicking in the button :

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
 DownloadService mService;
        boolean mBound = false;
....
private ServiceConnection mConnection = new ServiceConnection() {
        // Called when the connection with the service is established
        public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName DownloadService, IBinder service) {
            // Because we have bound to an explicit
            // service that is running in our own process, we can
            // cast its IBinder to a concrete class and directly access it.
            LocalBinder binder = (LocalBinder) service;
            mService = binder.getService();
            mBound = true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {
            Log.e("TAG", "onServiceDisconnected");
            mBound = false;
        }
    };
     @Override
        protected void onStart() {
            super.onStart();
            // Bind to LocalService
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, DownloadService.class);
            bindService(intent, mConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onStop() {
            super.onStop();
            // Unbind from the service
            if (mBound) {
                unbindService(mConnection);
                mBound = false;
            }
        }

    public void onButtonClick(View v) {
        if (mBound) {
            // Call a method from the LocalService.
            // However, if this call were something that might hang, then this request should
            // occur in a separate thread to avoid slowing down the activity performance.
            int num = mService.getRandomNumber();

            Toast.makeText(this, "number: " + num, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }


}
```